# regex negative lookahead to match everything but a specific string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using this regex to match any string other than foo:

```
^((?!(foo)).)*
```

It succeeds in matching and capturing anything other than foo but it also matches foo, just with no capture. Is there a way to make it not match foo at all?

Answer (score 2):

You must use anchor `$` also:

```
^(?:(?!foo).)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK2aL1/2)